# How can I simplify this Javascript with similar events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my homepage I have these five divs

```
<table id="nav">
        <tr>

        <td><a href="coding.html"><div id="pagecl">C O D I N G</div></a></td>
        <td><div id="pagecl" class="high">A R T W O R K</div></td>
        <td><div id="logo"><img src="imageswebbing/icon.png"></div></td>
        <td><a href="extras.html"><div id="pagecl" class="more">E X T R A S</div></a></td>
        <td><a href="about.html"><div id="pagecl" class="last">A B O U T</div></a></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

this is the corresponding css:

```
#nav {
    margin:300px auto auto auto;
}

#pagecl {
    height:40px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#151515;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
    opacity:0.7;
    font-family: Garamond;
    font-size:12px;
}

#logo {
    height:120px;
    width:120px;
}
```

And the javascript allows for slow fades with mouse enter and mouse leave, but if I only use the #pagecel id in the javascript, the intended effect is only seen on the first "Coding" div. That's why I added the class selectors for the other divs in the html and javascript. How do I condense this? There's probably a simple solution; I apologize for being a newbie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

   $('#pagecl').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
   });

   $('#pagecl').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
   });

   $('.high').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
   });

   $('.high').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
   });

   $('.more').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
   });

   $('.more').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
   });

   $('.last').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
   });

   $('.last').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
   });


});
```

Comment: ID's are unique, you can't use them more than once.

Comment: To expand on @adeneo's comment, while you *can* write IDs multiple places into your markup, to be considered *valid* markup, you should use IDs for unique items (therefore, only once per instance). Anything that falls into a repeatable unit should be designated with a class name. Using the same ID more than once can cause issues with scripting, beyond just simply failing validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IDs is unique identifiers. As per your statement **I have these five divs**

```
    <td><a href="coding.html"><div id="pagecl">C O D I N G</div></a></td>
    <td><div id="pagecl" class="high">A R T W O R K</div></td>
```

**make them unique** or you can use a class to identify them

You can optimize your jQuery code as

Use `,` to pass [**multiple selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pagecl, .high, .more, .last').hover(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    }, function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", .7);
    });
});
```

Also use [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), its `(selector).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )` is shorthand for:

```
$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );
```

Comment: Important to note in case the OP doesn't know - this is jQuery - you will have to add the dependency.

Comment: @user1477388, Please suggest which dependency you are refering

Comment: @mori57 Indeed, but when I posted my comment, there was no jQuery tag and there was no jQuery code in the snippet. The OP must have added it after I posted.

Answer (score 4):

Use a class to describe what you're doing, then use that class as the selector.

```
$('.menuItem').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
});
$('.menuItem').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
});
```

Then you don't need to have a bunch of selectors - just add the 'menuItem' class to anything you want that effect happening on.

Answer (score 1):

if you are targeting modern browsers, you don't need javascript for this.

use css transition with :hover.

CSS EXAMPLE:

```
#pagecl:hover{
  opacity:0;
 }

#pagecl {
 opacity:1;
 transition: opacity 1s;
 /*add vendor prefixes -webkit etc...*/
}
```

.

Answer (score 0):

You can always consider using a couple of subroutines to abstract repetitive behaviour:

```
function setMouseEvents(selector){
    $(selector).mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
    })
    $(selector).mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7);
    });
}

setMouseEvents('#pagecl');
setMouseEvents('.high');
//and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each one a class (x) also:

```
<div id="pagecl" class="last x">
```

notice you can have multiple classes (space separated) but not multiple id's...

then write once:

```
$('.x').mouseenter(function(){$(this).fadeTo("slow",1);});
$('.x').mouseleave(function(){$(this).fadeTo("slow",0.7);});
```

Comment: Stephen has already answered that, do you have something to add?

Comment: yeah space separated classes, and my code is easier (.7 is 0.7) for someone new to understand and my class is additional to his existing class so it should be written smaller as its of less significance to his main class '.last'

Answer (score 0):

I guess your not aware of multiple classes. In your problem using a class you can make it more flexible.

An element can have more than `one class` seperated by a space but only one `ID`

```
<div class="more not me yes ..." id="unique"></div>
```

more is one class and not is second class and me is third class applied on to the div tag

mouseenter and mouseleave are `= .hover(mouseenter,mouseleave);`

```
$('.menuItem').hover(
               function() {
                   $(this).fadeTo("slow",1);
               },function() {
                  $(this).fadeTo("slow",.7); 
});
```

So add this to all the elements that want a hover effect

example

```
<div id="pagecl" class="high menuItem">A R T W O R K</div>
```